# How to draw a chat balloon in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I am fairly new to kivy and I am trying to make a chatting application. I can easily make most my UI but I am unable to implement the chat page.
I want to have **WhatsApp like chat bubbles** to contain my chats.[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daly8.jpg)
But I am unable to make these bubbles in kivy. I am more comfortable with using .kv files.
I have tried to draw such a bubble in the canvas of label

```
Label:
        id:txt
        text: 'I am fine'  
        color: (0, 0.2, .4, 1)  
        
        text_size: self.size  
        halign: 'right'  
        valign: 'top'  
        bold: True  
        size_hint_x:0.8
        size_hint_y:0.05
        pos_hint:{'right':1}
        size:self.size
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1  
            RoundedRectangle:
                pos: self.pos 
                size:self.size 
                radius:20,0,20,20
```

but the resulting shape is not quite like the WhatsApp text bubbles. Also my bubbles don't work properly. The text overflows out of the box. I tried to add a size of the Label to wrap the text but that makes the size of the bubble fixed.
I am trying to make a **bubble that would adapt to the text size**. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rit77.jpg)
As you can see in the example that the size of the bubble depends on the size of the text but it **maintains a maximum horizontal width**.
It would be nice if someone would help me implement this design. Preferably using the **kv language**.
P.S. I am using Python 3.9 and the latest stable version of Kivy(2.0.0).

Comment: Take a look at this [example](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/widgets/recycleview/messenger.py)

Comment: I am unable to create such a widget. I recommend setting ```multiline:True```.

Comment: @Neizvestnyj Tnx...but I have been able to do that but those chat bubbles are not like what I want .I have mentioned that too that I have been able to make some sort of bubbles but they are not like what I want.

Comment: @Darnell tnx...I think that will address the overflow issue but overflowing is not the main problem I have at hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the `size_hint_y` to `None`, then set the `height` to `self.minimum_height`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).